# Power analysis for moderator effect and mediation analysis

Tags: interaction, statistical-power, mediation

I want to do an a priori analysis of minimum sample size with G*Power and I have two questions about this:

First, I will test an interaction effect for a moderator variable. I am not sure which statistical test to choose in G*Power as I am less interested in the overall $R^2$ and more interested in whether the interaction is significant.

Second, I will do a mediation analysis following the Baron & Kenny approach. Which statistical test do I have to choose here to calculate the minimum sample size?

I know about the G*Power tutorials, but I couldn't find anything about moderation- and mediation-analysis there. So I would be grateful if anybody could help me!